# Are there complete Boolean algebras with no non-trivial complete endomorphisms?

Tags: boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

I have read about the existence of rigid complete Boolean algebras that have no non-trivial automorphisms, and endo-rigid Boolean algebras that have only certain kinds of endomorphisms. So I was wondering:

- Are there any complete Boolean algebras that do not have any complete
  endomorphisms apart from the identity?

Comment: Perhaps this is included in the examples you mention, but Donald Monk (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02760942) provides a Boolean algebra whose endomorphisms all come from prime ideals. Since those are never complete (in an atomless algebra), this algebra has no nontrivial complete endomorphisms. But it may not be itself complete, and so this doesn't answer the question.